# Most efficient way to store a string in bytes?

Tags: string, byte

Say I have a simple bytecode-like file format for saving data.
If I want to store a string, should I do it like in source files where all characters between a certain byte is the string,
or should I first store the length of the string then the string bytes?

Or are both solutions horrible and if so which one can I use?

Comment: What did I do wrong for a downvote?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you want to store:

- a single string
- a number of strings

  - different length strings
  - all the same length

For all of the above, it may also matter if your strings contain:

- any characters
- only certain characters
- formatting

In general, you should use Unicode.
For a single string, you simply can use an entire file to contain the string, the end-of-file will be the same as the end of string. No need to store the length of the string.

If the strings aren't all (around) the same length you can use an inline separator to separate the strings. Often the newline character is useful for this (especially since a lot of programming languages support this way of reading in a file line-by-line), but other markers such as tab are common.

CSV text files often use double quotes to enclose strings that contain commas (or other column separator) (which would otherwise indicate the next column value was starting), or line-breaks (which would otherwise indicate the next row).
Of course, now you have the problem of how to store a double quote in your string.

If you want to store formatting, you can use a markup language (html) or it may be enough to allow for line breaks and/or some markdown.